# Windows phone 8 neon inline assembly ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, arm, windows-phone-8, inline-assembly, neon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [windows phone8 wp8 arm neon assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670196/windows-phone8-wp8-arm-neon-assembly)

I am about to transplant a project just like ffmpeg onto wp8(ARM). Unfortunately, most part of the project was written by arm neon inline assembly code (NEON inline assembly) with AT&T format..

Any suggestion about tools or methods to quickly doing that?  Or what should I do for that?

I asked this question before but closed for the reason which is not constructive but I do not think so because what I mentioned is INLINE assembly with AT&T.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be more descriptive of your problem. Post a piece of code to show what you are talking about, or mention the ultimate toolchain you want to use. AT&T is for x86s, high chance you are using the wrong words too.

Comment: AT&T inline assembly is common for gcc both for x86s and arm. In other word. If I have some inline assembly (neon) functions. Is it possible for me to transplant these funcs onto wp8?

Comment: meta-comment: Closing a question as a duplicate of one that's been closed as "non-constructive" isn't exactly constructive either ... that said, I share the sentiment that this inquiry lacks details - like, if your project isn't `ffmpeg` but "just like ...", then how much inline asm is there, how exactly does it look like / how complex is it, what methods have you tried to convert it (on ARM, there isn't really such a thing as "AT&T" syntax, the GNU as for ARM uses ARM's syntax just as Microsoft's does, but GCC inline asm style vs. MSVC inline asm style differrences still apply), etc ...

Answer (score 0):

nothing I have read about WP8 sdk tells me that it allows / supports assembly code. you will need to some how convert assembly to C++ and use it with Direct 3D

Comment: Is it Microsoft ARM Assembler available? (Microsoft ARMASM does not support inline assembly but it claims assembly file would be compiled. I am not for sure)

Comment: not publicly as far as I am aware.

Comment: Hermit is wrong - armasm ships with Visual Studio and can be easily plugged into the build system. Simulator builds, however, would need to provide equivalent Intel code.